# BeautifulSoup - Checking for Value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 with Python 2.7 to parse some XML files. The reason I'm using BS is that I know the documents will contain invalid headers, inconsistent encodings etc. though I don't know for certain that lxml etc. can't cope.

I'm trying to check if certain elements have a value so...

```
if soup.person.identifier.string is None:
    # reject file
```

Which is fine as long as the XML is:

```
<root>
    <person>
        <identifier><identifier>
    </person>
</root>
```

But if the "identifier" element is omitted entirely I get an error that "None does not have an attribute string".

My question is what is the neatest way to handle this? I'd prefer to avoid having to check first that the element exists before I check for a value.

There's

```
try:
    identifier = soup.something.identifier.string
except:
    identifier = None
if identifier is None:
    # reject file
```

but that too seems a bit long winded.

If I were using lxml I'd just do

```
if len(root.xpath('person/identifier/text()') == 0
```

Which would handle both.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like:

`items = [item for item in soup.find_all(name='somethingelse') if item.text == ""]`

ex.

```
import bs4

string = """
<root>
    <something>
        <somethingelse></somethingelse>
        <somethingelse>haha</somethingelse>
    </something>
</root>
"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(string, 'lxml')

items = [item for item in soup.find_all(name='somethingelse') if item.text == ""]
```

output: `[<somethingelse></somethingelse>]`

and it won't break if it can't find one

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm trying to do. I've re-written the examples with more relevant names which hopefully will make it clearer. Basically I need to do a lot of checks on a document to see if the required information has been supplied - and then do further checks on its validity if it has.

Comment: hm, maybe I'm still a little confused, but the `items` variable I create has a list of whatever element you're trying to find with blank text. If there are no elements, it will not throw an error but will be empty. So you can just check `len(items)` if you want to see if anything was found

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was -

```
def bv(value_string, locals):
    try:
        result = eval(value_string, globals(), locals)
    except AttributeError:
        result = None
    return result
```

bv('person.identifier.string', locals())

This works but I suspect there's a better way to do this.